# vue iterate over object with arrays

Tags: json, loops, vue.js, object, nuxt.js

i have this piece of code. i want to iterate over an multiple object with arrays on it. no return data is displaying. please help me with my code.

heres is the sample json data from an api:

```
"sections": [
        {
            "name": "Article",
            "position": 1,
            "contents": [
                {
                    "title": "Corporate Profile",
                    "body": "<p style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris volutpat ligula vitae egestas ornare. Proin lobortis tempus bibendum. Nam porttitor, est sit amet molestie hendrerit, ipsum diam consequat augue, nec euismod metus felis eu est. Maecenas sollicitudin elit purus, non venenatis dui mollis ut. Nulla aliquet interdum interdum. Fusce ornare leo eu auctor aliquam. Donec vel elit nunc. Aenean molestie lectus vel euismod blandit. Nulla libero justo, bibendum ut eros nec, tempor volutpat sapien. Curabitur id justo quis ipsum interdum pharetra. Sed condimentum arcu odio, id tincidunt neque pretium in. Donec feugiat augue orci, id elementum justo feugiat nec.</p><p style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">Donec vel massa vitae est faucibus commodo. Donec eget elementum nulla, sit amet hendrerit libero. Vestibulum ullamcorper nibh in magna gravida, nec commodo ex commodo. Donec ut odio nibh. Suspendisse semper ornare orci id tempor. Nullam in ultrices diam, vel cursus justo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras consectetur, magna in vehicula iaculis, dolor metus porttitor sem, vitae volutpat orci nisl at mauris. Vivamus tincidunt rutrum velit in gravida. Nulla odio mi, hendrerit vitae velit quis, ultricies volutpat urna. Aliquam interdum libero velit, vel tempus lectus rutrum vitae. Morbi at mattis nibh. Sed finibus tortor at neque convallis, a tincidunt est finibus. Fusce purus risus, scelerisque et quam eget, varius gravida ex. Etiam consequat, lectus eu facilisis molestie, quam enim molestie felis, id commodo lectus ipsum non nunc. Mauris at luctus purus, vitae sodales ipsum.</p>",
                    "position": 1,
                    "_locale": "en"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Key Milestones",
                    "body": "<p style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel nulla mollis, interdum ipsum eu, tincidunt erat. Duis fringilla nibh est, vel pulvinar velit ornare non. Fusce ac rhoncus dolor. Ut cursus nunc ut efficitur convallis. Donec quis metus nec est euismod vestibulum. Vestibulum aliquam urna risus. Pellentesque fermentum leo vel posuere volutpat. Ut eleifend consectetur diam, vel interdum sapien.</p><p style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">Pellentesque ac elementum est, in consequat tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse eu ipsum tristique mauris vehicula pulvinar vitae ut sapien. Vestibulum non molestie mi. Nullam euismod eros magna, vel feugiat magna finibus id. Curabitur iaculis quis elit in hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam ligula mauris, tempor tristique ante a, posuere rhoncus ligula.</p><p style=\"margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">Quisque ut vulputate quam. Pellentesque tempor vestibulum justo, vitae fringilla purus porta vel. Cras nec pretium urna. Nunc faucibus molestie ante, non porta arcu consequat eget. Ut eget purus porttitor, accumsan urna eget, tempor felis. Nulla id tempus diam. Fusce ut arcu lacus. Pellentesque mollis eros nec porta posuere.</p>",
                    "position": 2,
                    "_locale": "en"
                }
            ],
            "section_type": {
                "code": "Article",
                "name": "Article"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I only want to iterate over the sections.contents object arrays.

```
async getContents() {
        let res = await this.$axios.get(`/page/${this.$route.params.slug}?token=9d04c2c980aab37a16976b463a3df8776e402444963bb92fd4456c1eca354xyz`);
        let datas = res.data.page.sections;
        if(res.data.success){
            this.datas = datas;
            console.log('sections', this.datas)
        }else{
            this.messages = res.messages;
        }
    },

<div class="row">
            <div class="col" v-for="(sub, ind) in datas.contents" :key="ind">
              <h3>{{ sub.title }}</h3>
              <p v-html="sub.body"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have two `contents` arrays in your `sections`. Are you only trying to iterate through the `Contact Us` one?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through every `contents` array separately in a new row, or are you trying to concatenate all arrays together?

Comment: @Excalibaard i edit my code. im trying to iterate all through the contents object.

Comment: @bassxzero i updated my code json object. theres a change that theres a  multiple content per section get from api.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code: `datas.contents === undefined`, as datas is the sections array and first you need to select which index you're reading the object with contents from. `datas[0].contents` targets the first object's contents for example. You can automatically loop through the sections array first, and then through the contents of each in order to automatically loop through the different section objects.

Assuming you want a new row for every 'section', this should work:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(section, sectionIdx) in datas" :key="'section-'+ sectionIdx">
  <div class="col" v-for="(content, contentIdx) in section.contents" :key="'section-' + sectionIdx + '-content-' + contentIdx">
    <h3>{{ content.title }}</h3>
    <p v-html="content.address"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```